# How to add :hover and click event to element same time?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class, dom-events

When I hover parent element his child is appear. When I click parent element his child also appear and when I click it again his child disappear. But then(after clicking parent element for disappearing child) when I hover parent element his child is not appearing. Why?

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li');
var children = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li > ul');

parent.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (children.style.display == 'block') {
    children.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    children.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

li {
  width: max-content;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The JavaScript adds an inline style to the element that is overriding your stylesheet

Comment: Issue is when you set the css property directly on the elements, it specificity is greater than the styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily avoid this by setting `children.style.display` to *the empty string* instead of assigning `none` to it when you want to hide the children.

**EDIT:**

Need a correction: Instead of undefined the empty string needs to be assigned to `children.style.display` to drop the override (see the text marked in italics - I had to correct that).

The code snippet should look like this:

```
var parent = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li');
var children = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li > ul');

parent.addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert(children.style.display);
  if (children.style.display == 'block') {
    children.style.display = '';
  } else {
    children.style.display = 'block';
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: The point is that assigning an explicit value to `children.style.display` overrides the CSS definition. Unsetting this value (i. e. setting it to undefined) removes this override.

Comment: So please, copy the asker code and create a snippet showing it work. You can [edit] your answer and click at `<>`. Working snippets area bonus that usually earn you more upvotes

Comment: @Calvin Nunes: Thanks for the hint, though. I have applied your suggestions - and promptly ran into a problem myself with the code.

Comment: Yes, I knew that undefined won't work, thats why I incentivated the snippet, a zero length string would work, as you edited your answer now. So, know I'll upvote you

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to toggle a class when the parent is clicked.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li');
var children = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li > ul');

parent.addEventListener('click', function() {
  children.classList.toggle("showIt");
});
```

```css
nav>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

li {
  width: max-content;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

.showIt {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use basic programming composition

```
$('#target').on('click mouseover', function () {
// Do something for both
});
```

Comment: The mouseover is overkill if you can just do it with CSS.